# How to encrypt webm file using Clear Key to play with Google's Shaka Player?

Tags: html, encryption, ffmpeg, drm, webm

I'm developing a small system which will be used to streaming protected content over the web with MSE/EME API.

This is some tools I'm using:

- [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html)
- Google's [Shaka-Packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager)
- [webm_crypt](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17d6_KX5jX0gY1ygYbjqOEdVzuUGkPO53wL8t40dMGeQ/edit#)

I can create .webm file and package them using shaka-packager into mpd file in order to feed to shaka-player. But following by the [Clear Key section in the Shaka docs](http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html) I have to encrypt webm file require pair of `KeyId` and `Key`.
By using webm_crypt, I can created encrypted content by follow [this document on 2.2.7](http://wiki.webmproject.org/zz-obsolete/instructions-to-playback-a-webm-dash-presentation) but I have no idea how to get the key pairs for the shaka-player DRM system.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Clear Key, you configure the player with a list of key servers. The player makes a JSON request to a key server (the request is in [this format](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/#clear-key-request-format)) and the key server provides a "license" -- [JSON response containing the Base64-encoded symmetric key and keyId](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/#clear-key-license-format). That symmetric key is then used to decrypt the content.

**Update**

To associate a key ID with an unprotected content key to debug with ClearKey, provide a JSON element for `drm.clearKeys` with the keyId(s) in hex encoding as the "key" of a map and the "value" is the hex-encoded content encryption key.

```
player.configure({
  drm: {
    clearKeys: {
      'deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef': '18675309186753091867530918675309',
      '02030507011013017019023029031037': '03050701302303204201080425098033'
    }
  }
});
```

Associate the same keyId with the media file when encrypting it or in the manifest file that accompanies it.

[Encrypting media file with mp4split](http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/package/mpeg-dash.html#creating-the-media-files-with-common-encryption):

```
#!/bin/bash

KID=10000000100010001000100000000001
CEK=3a2a1b68dd2bd9b2eeb25e84c4776668
LAURL="http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx?PlayRight=1&UseSimpleNonPersistentLicense=1"
PSSH=YOUR_PSSH

mp4split --package_mpd -o audio.mp4 \
  --iss.key=${KID}:${CEK} --iss.license_server_url=${LAURL} \
  --widevine.key=${KID}:${CEK} --widevine.drm_specific_data=${PSSH} \
  oceans-64k.mp4

mp4split --package_mpd -o video-1.mp4 \
  --iss.key=${KID}:${CEK} --iss.license_server_url=${LAURL} \
  --widevine.key=${KID}:${CEK} --widevine.drm_specific_data=${PSSH} \
  oceans-250k.mp4

mp4split --package_mpd -o video-2.mp4 \
  --iss.key=${KID}:${CEK} --iss.license_server_url=${LAURL} \
  --widevine.key=${KID}:${CEK} --widevine.drm_specific_data=${PSSH} \
  oceans-380k.mp4
```

For `webm_crypt`, the documentation is very sketchy, but I believe it's done with the `content_id=0123456789ABCDEF` command-line flag in `-video_options`:

```
foo@bar-linux:~/chromium_code/webm_crypt/webm_crypt$ ./webm_crypt 
    -i mediafiles/Chrome_44_5sec-chunks_video_only.webm -video true -audio false 
    -video_options base_file=bear.key,content_id=0123456789012345 
    -o /home/foo/www/no_crawl/eme/media/Chrome_44_5sec-chunks_video‌​_only-enc_v_01234567‌​89012345.webm
```

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks you but I'm facing the problem of encrypted media CREATION (webm_crypt). I don't know how to create it. Not the way how to transfer it for decryption process. I need to generate keyid:key pair using webm_crypt but didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, your initial question said you could create the encrypted content. The [Readme](https://github.com/webmproject/webm-tools/blob/master/webm_crypt/Readme.txt) in `webm_crypt` gives instructions for building the tool and executing it. This [walkthrough](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17d6_KX5jX0gY1ygYbjqOEdVzuUGkPO53wL8t40dMGeQ/edit) also gives step-by-step instructions for encrypting media using `webm_crypt`.

Comment: Example from document: `foo@bar-linux:~/chromium_code/webm_crypt/webm_crypt$ ./webm_crypt -i mediafiles/Chrome_44_5sec-chunks_video_only.webm -video true -audio false -video_options base_file=bear.key,content_id=0123456789012345 -o /home/foo/www/no_crawl/eme/media/Chrome_44_5sec-chunks_video_only-enc_v_0123456789012345.webm`

Comment: Yes I could create it, but couldn't get the key pairs for shaka player like this: http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html (please check the Clear Key section). And I won't provide the key through license server, only plain json for testing first.

Comment: Which license server are you using? PlayReady and [Widevine](https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/protecting-your-content-using-google-widevine) appear to be the popular options for IE and Chrome respectively. Those license servers generate the keys and provide them via client software to generate the encrypted content as well. If you're not using one, I guess you'll have to generate the keys yourself, store them in a secure system, and provide the JSON license on request for decryption.

Comment: If you're providing the plain keys for verification, just provide the hex encoding of the key (the content of `base_file`) that you used in `webm_crypt` to encrypt the content in the `drm.Clearkeys` JSON object associated with the key ID.

Comment: That's great but I'm not using both of them. I'm trying to use Clear Key system.

Comment: That is what I need. But I don't know how to associated the key with key id after using webm_crypt. Could you please update the answer for that?

Comment: Hi, I have already checked all of the documents above in recent days. I don't need the mp4 encryption cause I can create it easily by using Bento4 `mp4encrypt`. But I'm not sure what content_id and initialize_iv present for in webm_crypt (which is key, which is keyid)? So I have to open this question on S.O :(

Comment: `content_id` is the keyId; `initialize_iv` is the initialization vector, and the contents of `base_file` is the key.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: @NamPham did this work for you? The bounty period ended 18 hours ago. Please let me know if you encountered further difficulties.

Comment: @Andy I'm using `packager` for encryption and am confused when it comes to clearkey. if am not wrong, keyId should be in hex but the two keyIds in this answer are not in hex. For `packager`, i have provided `--content_id "6b65792d7769646576696e655f746573742e747874"`, how can i use this to generate keyId and key itself? i haven't understand where the two come from. are they just imaginary hex?. Another thing, do i have to provide those two sets of `key:keyIds`? can one be enough?

Comment: hello @Andy, can you provide an example of `base_file=bear.key` file?, how to generate it is it GPG key, and how it is related to clear keys?